# how can i write a method to check characters whether it matches the argument?

Tags: java, string

```
class A{
private String name ;

public A(String name){
    this.name = name ;
}


public boolean isName(String nameCheck){
    boolean is = true ;
    if(nameCheck.matches(name)){
        return is;
    }else return !is ;

}
}
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    A object = new A("CHIU Shun Kin");

    System.out.println(object.isName("?HIU Sh?? ?in"));

}
```

}

My main duty is to check the input name whether it matches the defined one(variable name) but "?" character will not be compared. The above is my code. I can't find out how to not compare the "?" character.

Here's the sample:

name:       “CHIU Shun Kin”

nameCheck:  “?HIU Sh?? ?in”  returns true

nameCheck:  “CKIU Sh?? ?in”  returns false

Comment: Use nameCheck.equals(name)

Comment: compare the chars in each string in a for loop.

Comment: how can i don't compare the question mark in a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method without Regex? Check by one character in string if it equals your pattern or `?` (can be variable in this case). Try this one:

```
public boolean isName(String check, char ch) {

    for (int i=0; i<name.length(); i++) {
        if (name.charAt(i) != check.charAt(i) && ch != check.charAt(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
A object = new A("CHIU Shun Kin");
System.out.println(object.isName("?HIU Sh?? ?in", '?')); // returns TRUE
System.out.println(object.isName("CKIU Sh?? ?in", '?')); // returns FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you did it. I made a little bit change to your code but it's still works .Thanks !!!

Answer (score 8):

You could use a regex.

```
String regex = "?HIU Sh?? ?in".replaceAll("\\?", "."); // change your format to a regex

boolean matches = "CHIU Shun Kin".matches(regex);
```

So in your case you need

```
public boolean isName(String nameCheck) {
    return name.matches(Pattern.quote(nameCheck).replaceAll("\\\\?", "."));
}
```

The `Pattern.quote` is to ensure no other symbols are given a special meaning.

Comment: Um... That's too complicated to me , i haven't learn regex  yet. Is there any easier way to do this one?

Answer (score 2):

> how can i write a method to check characters whether it matches the argument?

If you want to apply those basics you learn in school on this problem, you can simply iterate through the String to check those characters which is not a `?` and match with the characters in the same position from the given name:

```
public boolean isName(String givenName){
    if(name.length() != givenName.length())
        return false;
    for(int x=0; x<name.length(); x++)
        if(name.charAt(x) != '?' && name.charAt(x) != givenName.charAt(x))
            return false;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: @Michael You may want to check on the String length first. See my example.

Answer (score 1):

1) Compare length
2) 
For loop on each char on proposed name
 if ?
  continue
 else //other
  compare the same char in the model
  if false
   end//not match, return false
  else
   continue//still matching
return true//matching at the end of the comparison

But it's better with a regexp, regexp are made for this, it's not easy to understand at the beginning but this is the best solution. You can test regexp on different 'regexp tester' on the web to try it by yourself.